# Facing issue with sed command

Tags: shell

I have a file with below entries:

```
 ./test/test1/test2
 ./abc/abc1/abc2
 ./bcd/bcd1/bcd2
```

I want to remove <kbd>space</kbd>, `.`, and `/` from the starting of each line of the file using `sed` command. I am using the below `sed` command for this:

```
sed 's/^[ ]\.\//'
```

but is removing only the <kbd>space</kbd> and `.`, but not the `/`.

I am not able to figure out how to remove `/` as well. Can someone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a final `/` in `sed`'s `s` command:

```
sed 's/^[ ]\.\///'
                ^--needed to complete the replacement string.
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. The solution is giving me below error: 

sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'

Comment: @PaulIT the command works fine for me (`sed 's/^[ ]\.\///' sed-input-file`).  The error you are getting suggests you have another character after the final `/`.

Comment: If the regular expression you're matching has a `/`, it's easier to use a different character as the delimiter: `s#^[ ]\./##`.